# Remove unwanted folders from User folder

Tags: windows-7

I have several folders in my user profile directory that I don't think belong there.  For most of the unwanted folders, the folder name begins with a dot.

[image: Unwanted folders]

It seems like these belong in the AppData folder instead.  Is something screwed up in my system, like a bad environment variable, or are apps actually creating these annoying directories at the root of my user directory on purpose?

I want to get rid of them.  Is it safe or possible to just move these into the AppData directory myself.  I'm guessing not, but I figure it doesn't hurt to ask.  Maybe there is a tool that can do this.  But, probably, if I want to move them, I'll have to go into each application and change the settings manually.  Or worse, muck with the registry manually.

As an alternative, is it safe to just mark these folders as hidden?  Can that mess anything up?

Comment: IMO you have linked your Android device with libraries somehow. So I think there should no problem to delete them or hide them from here.

Comment: All of those folders were created by an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix/Linux, [a file or directory that begins with a dot is hidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments).  It stands to reason that the developers of the apps that created those directories intended for them to be hidden.

Manually hiding the folders works fine and causes no ill effects.  Moving the folders only works (as I suspected) if the owner application exposes a setting to control the location of the directory. In my case at least, most of the applications don't expose any such setting.  (Happily, GIMP does)

I consider this to be a bug in these applications, or at least sloppy programming.  If the folder was intended to be hidden, the application should have explicitly set it to be hidden for Windows and not just Unix/Linux.  Better still would be to put these folders in the AppData directory, itself a hidden folder, and left them visible within that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Windows restore point, then move the files to the recycle bin, restart, see if it causes any issues, if it does cause issues, either move the files back from the recycle bin, or if you cannot do that perform a Windows System Restore and pick your restore point you made earlier.

If it keeps the user profile from loading (unlikely) system restore can be run from the Windows Recovery Environment (F8) or boot from a W7 system repair disc to run recovery.

I have one of these .folder in my user folder, it appears an installed program put it there and I don't use android devices with my pc, they are more than likely legitimate folders.

Comment: I'm pretty sure deleting the directories is not an option - I can see based on create/modify dates that the files in these directories are being used.  I'd like to move them to the AppData directory if possible, or otherwise set them to be hidden folders.

Comment: @gilly3 - While you could move them yourself they were created by a program that doesn't create files the correct way.

Comment: @gilly3 Not sure how programs treat hidden folders, interesting question.